# mysql - group by range of years performance

Tags: mysql

I need to group by range of years starting from date of birth. This is what I've done so far. If you run the stored procedure with 500000 records and then the query I wrote you'll see that it takes about 25 seconds. How can I improve it?

```
create table people(
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
`dob` date
);

delimiter //
drop procedure if exists date_random //
create procedure date_random(in low date,in upp date,in number int)
begin
declare i int default 0;
while i < number do
    begin
    insert into people (`dob`)  values ( low + interval rand()* datediff(upp,low) day  );
    set i = i + 1;
    end;
end while;
end //
delimiter ;

call date_random('1910-01-01',curdate(),500000);


delimiter // 
create function `age`(dob date) returns int(11)
no sql
begin
return (year(curdate())-year(dob))-(right(curdate(),5)< right(dob,5) );
end //

delimiter ;


explain select sql_no_cache
concat_ws('-',min(age(dob)),max(age(dob))) as years,
count(*) as total
from people
group by if(age(dob)=0,1,ceil(age(dob)/5))
```

This is the output of explain

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | people | index | NULL          | ip   | 4       | NULL | 500000 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: If the `EXPLAIN` says it's doing lots of linear scans, you could start by indexing the `dob` column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to say that I had already add an index to dob field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'age' function could be more efficient. instead of forcing mysql to cast dates into strings, do substrings, compare them, then cast to numbers for the final subtraction, how about `(year(now()) - year(dob))  - (dayofyear(now()) < dayofyear(dob))` - keeps it all numeric and eliminates at least one layer of casting.

As well, since it's using native date/time functions, it increases the chances that MySQL can use an index on the `dob` column. Your current method is impossible to handle with indexes, since you're deriving text values from a date field dynamically at query time.

Comment: Hi Marc. Thanks for your reply. Following your advice I've created a new function age2. I've tried my query with your function version but it takes the same time, about 25 seconds. The output of explain is always the same.

Comment: The other option is to go shotgun and create an 'age' column. Do a table update to precalculate/index that, then use it in your comparisons, see if that affects the time. The only drawback is that you get a small window where the query could straddle someone's birthday and you get a slight chance of incorrect data due to that.

Comment: You're right. If I add the age field to the table                                                               select sql_no_cache
concat_ws('-',min(age),max(age)) as years,
count(*) as total
from people
group by if(age=0,1,ceil(age/5))

the query takes 0.5 seconds. So the problem was the function calling within the query. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, all those year/dayofyear/substr calls made it impossible to use an index. So, for performance you'll have to denormalize a bit and use a derived field. As long as the calcuation of that field isn't too onerous, this shouldn't be a problem. Just remember to update it each time you want to run the main query, or you'll be working off stale age data.